# Firebase phone authentication doesn't work on release variant

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've tried all the questions I could find regarding this:

- Added SHA-1 and SHA-256 to the app in Firebase console (for debug,
  release and the one Google-Play generated).
- Rebuild the project on Firebase.
- I don't use Google cloud so I don't have a restricted key.
- I've set minifyEnabled to false

Error code:

```
2021-03-17 14:27:44.978 31822-31899/dhsolutions.lifehelpers.paynow E/FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
2021-03-17 14:27:45.069 31822-31822/dhsolutions.lifehelpers.paynow E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
2021-03-17 14:27:45.636 31822-31849/dhsolutions.lifehelpers.paynow E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
2021-03-17 14:27:45.657 31822-31822/dhsolutions.lifehelpers.paynow E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztt.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.3:26)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzux.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.3:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuy.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.3:3)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

If any additional code is necessary please let me know and I will add it.

Comment: Did you enable SafetyNet or reCAPTCHA verification to authenticate with Firebase  using a Phone Number?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that you haven't enabled device verification API (also known as Android DeviceCheck API) yet for your project. Go to Google Developers Console, select your project, search for Android Device Verification API and click on enable. You may refer this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification).